# Use of global variables in static methods

Tags: axapta, x++

I need to assign a value to a global variable in a static method. Since I need that variable in a derived class.

But the problem is we are not able to use global variables in static methods.

Comment: Maybe give more background information about your goal. Global variables are implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Use global variables.  They're pretty easy.  See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa891830.aspx

One thing to note...if you're using global variables for something, it's most likely a flawed implementation design and there are probably other ways of accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi , thanks for that.. i had gone through that but its kind of confusing since i am using them for the first time. I need to assign a string value in the parent class and use them in the child class. How do i do that. Can u please guide me

Comment: But you stated that the access was in a static method. Static methods does not have access to instance variables. Static methods cannot be overridden. Then why do you talk about parent/child classes?

Comment: It sounds like you need to make a class variable in the class declaration of a parent class, then create a parm method to access that.  Then from the child class you can pass that to the static method.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: guys, sorry my question was unclear. my requirement is exactly like the one described by Alex .. i got the solution by creating a parm method ...

Comment: Hopefully I was able to help then...please mark one of the answers as solved then.  I'd say the one below this is correct for your case.

Answer (score 1):

> Tejashree S: I need to assign a string value in the parent class and use them in the child class.

To do this, you add a variable to the parent class's Class Declaration, then create a parm method in the parent class.

From the child class, you will be able to access the variable directly or via the parm method.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of the parent class in the static method and access the variable with the object name.
Suppose Class is Test then create an object
like,
Test obj= new Test();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).